# What is the difference between "selbst", "mich selbst", and "mir selbst"?

Tags: difference, reflexive

As the title of this question says, what would be the difference between those three?

For example, I found this sentence:

> Ich werde das Buch **selbst** behalten.

Why is it not

> Ich werde das Buch **mich selbst** behalten

or

> Ich werde das Buch **mir selbst** behalten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The difference is in the case.**

Rearrange the sentence and you'll get:

> **Ich selbst** werde das Buch behalten.

This is the nominative case of the personal pronoun *ich*.

In the dative case you have:

> **Mir selbst** ist es noch nicht passiert. (It didn't happen to me, yet)

and in the accusative case

> **Mich selbst** betrifft es nicht. (It doesn't affect myself)

I can't think of a genitive sentence, however, if you use *Selbst* as a noun, you can use it in a more sophisticated style,  like

> Ich war nicht mehr Herr meiner Selbst (I was no longer in control of myself)